# How to instantiate multi dimensional array in JavaScript?

Tags: javascript, arrays, indexing

Simply what I need to do is:

```
var a = [[[]]]; 
a[1][2][3] = "hello!"; // [...[undefined,undefined,undefined,"hello!"]...];
a[1][2][1] = "a"; // [...[undefined,"a",undefined,"hello!"]...]
a[2][3][4] = "new_index" // [...[undefined,"a",undefined,"hello!"]...[undefinedx4, "new_index"]]
```

In my case i prefer not to instantiate the size of array until the index is specified and increase the size when is required by larger index. 
What is the easiest or cleanest way to do it in javascript since js is weak supporting multi dimentional array?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In JS arrays are reference types so creating an ND array is tricky. A cloninig tool  would be very handy. Accordingly you may do as follows;

```js
Array.prototype.clone = function(){
  return this.map(e => Array.isArray(e) ? e.clone() : e);
};
function arrayND(...n){
  return n.reduceRight((p,c) => c = (new Array(c)).fill().map(e => Array.isArray(p) ? p.clone() : p ));
}

var arr = arrayND (2,3,4,"x")
console.log(JSON.stringify(arr));
```

The initial arguments define the dimensions and the very last argument is the fill value.

And this should work fine with pre ES6 compatible browsers;

```js
Array.prototype.clone = function(){
  return this.map(function(e){
                    return Array.isArray(e) ? e.clone() : e;
                  });
};

function arrayND(){
  var n = Array.prototype.slice.call(arguments);
  return n.reduceRight(function(p,c){
                         return c = Array(c).fill().map(function(e){
                                                          return Array.isArray(p) ? p.clone() : p;
                                                        });
                       });
}

var arr = arrayND (2,3,4,"x");
console.log(JSON.stringify(arr));
```

Comment: @Dragon Night I might have not been very clear... It'a all about initializing. You may fill them with `undefined` if you want to... The point is, once you create your ND array then you may assign any value at any specific index by doing `myArr[x][y]...[z] = "whatever"`

Comment: The problem is when I write arrayND(3,4,5,"x") it generates what you mentioned but again for another index I cannot use it. it overrides the previous array. when I increment index or increase the size, it wont work too. overrides everytime.

Comment: @Dragon Night When you create an array with `arr = arrayND(2,3,4,"x")` you create a 3D array like an array filled with 2 arrays filled with 3 arrays each filled with 4 items each (`"x"` in this case). When you do like `arr[1][2][3] = "test"` you will have the the forth item in the third array of the second array of the main array assigned `"test"`. Please try.

Comment: Thanks for your answer. I tried to improve my question and example. would you have look please.

Comment: @Dragon Night  Well OK. In JS the point is, you can't arbitrarily assign items to a non existent object. So if `var a = []` you can not `say a[0][0] = "whatever"` You have to make it like `a[0] = []; a[0][0] = "whatever";` That is why we are initializing our ND array in the first place, while you can always extend your already existing 2D array like `arr[x][y] = []; arr.[x][y][n] = "whatever"` into 3D. However you can not do it on the fly without assigning an array to your extension point in advance.

Comment: @Dragon Night Please check the second snippet to see if it is ok with Safari 9...

Comment: great, thanks, I used arrayND([n]) and callbacks instead of arrow function like you and it worked.

Answer (score 1):

Here is my solution:

```js
function assign(input) {
    if ('object' !== typeof input) {
        let tmp = {};

        tmp[input] = arguments[1];
        input = tmp;
    }

    let regex = /\.?([^.\[\]]+)|\[(\d+)]/g;
    let result = {};

    for (let p in input) {
        let data = result, prop = '', match;

        while (match = regex.exec(p)) {
            data = data[prop] || (data[prop] = (match[2] ? [] : {}));
            prop = match[2] || match[1];
        }

        data[prop] = input[p];
    }

    return result[''];
}

// Example usage
let a = assign('3[4][5]', 'hello');
let b = assign('3[4][5][6]', 'world!');
let c = assign('you.can.use.object.as.well', 'cool!');
let d = assign('or.mix[3].them[2]', 'together!');
let e = assign({'with.multiple': 'properties', 'in.a.single': 'object'});

let f = assign({
    '[1][2][3]': "hello!",
    '[1][2][1]': "a",
    '[2][3][4]': "new_index"
});

console.log(a[3][4][5], '->', JSON.stringify(a));
console.log(b[3][4][5][6], '->', JSON.stringify(b));
console.log(c.you.can.use.object.as.well, '->', JSON.stringify(c));
console.log(d.or.mix[3].them[2], '->', JSON.stringify(d));
console.log(e.with.multiple, '->', e.in.a.single, '->', JSON.stringify(e));

console.log('f[1][2][3]:', f[1][2][3]);
console.log('f[1][2][1]:', f[1][2][1]);
console.log('f[2][3][4]:', f[2][3][4]);
```

Comment: Thanks for your answer. I tried to improve my question and example. would you have look please.

Comment: @DragonKnight I updated the example to show you how to use assign function in your use case.